# Can not add project to tomcat server in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, tomcat9

I am using Spring Tool Suite 4 Version: 4.4.2.RELEASE.

I created a new maven project with following POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xi</groupId>
  <artifactId>FitnessTracker</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>FitnessTracker Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>FitnessTracker</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

In Spring Tool Suite, it looks like this:

[image]

Then I try to add a tomcat server (I already downloaded tomecat 9, no problem on the path).

[image]

[image]

But in above window, my project is not shown in the left hand side available resource. I can create this tomcat 9 server, and I can start it, but I can't add my project under the server. Why?

BTW, my project facet is like this if you feel it is a issue:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

check once it is jar file or war file. if it jar file server not able to fetched.
if Not then do left click on project -> run as server.

Comment: How to check or change from jar to war in the IDE?

Comment: for check double click on pom.xml where you get overview option click on it. for change do change from the same place and save it futher, follow some article how to change from jar to war.